# TreeView does not update when modified. Windows Forms

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, treeview

I have a Windows Forms C# application which deals with TreeView and uses a separate thread to update it. 
Update launched by button click:

```
    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        vc.ChangeTree(treeView1);
    }
```

ChangeTree() starts UpdateTree() in a separate thread to update the TreeView asynchronously. 
Here I just need to use Thread for this:

```
    public void ChangeTree(TreeView tree)
    {
        Thread thread4 = new Thread(() => { UpdateTreeView(tree); });
        thread4.Name = "Thread 4";
        thread4.IsBackground = true;
        thread4.Start();
    }
```

UpdateTree() simply invokes the TreeView and adds nodes from another tree to it. Note that there aren't time consuming operations. The GetTree() just returns another TreeView:

```
    private void UpdateTreeView(TreeView tree)
    {
        if (tree.InvokeRequired)
        {
            tree.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
            {
                UpdateTreeView(tree);
            });
        }
        else
        {
            tree.Nodes.Clear();
            foreach (var node in GetTree().Nodes)
            {
                tree.Nodes.Add(node as TreeNode);
            }
            //Application.DoEvents(); // doesn't help
        }
    }
```

The problem is that it actually adds nodes to the tree, but form does not show it. I checked the treeView1.Nodes after i clicked the button. It contains the nodes I need.

The Application.DoEvents() does not help, even though it may, according to my search. Neither does treeView1.Refresh().

If i click the button twice, treeView1 updates as I planned. But I don't know why and, obviously, I don't need such behavior.

So here is the question. How to make it update with one click?

---

It turns out that TreeNode can't be used by more than one TreeView.

**The solution** I found is to use treeNode.Clone():

```
tree.Nodes.Add((node as TreeNode).Clone() as TreeNode);
```

**But** I still don't understand why the initial code worked, even though it took two times for it.

Comment: Have you tried `tree.Invalidate()` after the `foreach` loop?

Comment: @Übercoder yes, no result

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that one TreeNode cannot be changed from one TreeView to another

This is my test code that works:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ChangeTree(treeView1);
        }

        public void ChangeTree(TreeView tree)
        {
            Thread thread4 = new Thread(() => { UpdateTreeView(tree); });
            thread4.Name = "Thread 4";
            thread4.IsBackground = true;
            thread4.Start();
        }

        private void UpdateTreeView(TreeView tree)
        {
            if (tree.InvokeRequired)
            {
                tree.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
                {
                    UpdateTreeView(tree);
                });
            }
            else
            {
                tree.Nodes.Clear();
                foreach (var node in GetTree())
                {
                    tree.Nodes.Add(node as TreeNode);
                }
            }
        }

        private List<TreeNode> GetTree()
        {
            var result = new List<TreeNode>();

            result.Add(new TreeNode("changed"));

            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

If I change the `GetTree()` function into

```
    private TreeView GetTree()
    {
        var result = new TreeView();

        result.Nodes.Add(new TreeNode("changed"));

        return result;
    }
```

And revert the `UpdateTreeView` function into what it was before, it behaves like you described

Comment: It turns out that TreeNode can't be used by more than one TreeView. So in order to do it I had to treeNode.Clone() it or to store TreeNodes not in TreeView.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try setting the focus back to the treeview? With TreeView.Focus() this causes a refresh.